# How i will increase or decrease size of text in Tab button

Tags: android

Any body please tell me how we can decrease or increase size of text in Tab button . Is it possible to do so??    I want use some large text in App. 
Please help me.....
Thanks in advance

Comment: How i will increase it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When  we add tabs to our TabHost, we use TabHost.newTabSpec() to create a TabSpec object.  Using the default tab look, we would call setIndicator(String, Drawable) on the TabSpec (passing the text and image we want displayed on the tab), and then call setContent(intent) on the TabSpec, passing an intent for an Activity we want to be used as that tab’s content.  However, in this case, we want to use a custom layout for the tabs, and we want to simply use the Views defined in our tab_activity_layout.xml for the content, instead of individual Activities.

For custom tabs, first, we must define the custom layout of our tabs as a layout resource file.  Then we will programatically inflate a View object using that layout, set whatever attributes we want, and pass it into TabSpec.setIndicator(View).  Here is a very simple example layout, and some of the code to use it: Please check the link

[Custom View for Tab](http://www.speakingcode.com/2011/12/01/creating-custom-views-for-tabs-in-an-android-activity-using-tabhost-and-tabwidget/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code `yourEditText.setTextSize(16);` 
or if you use the .xml `android:textSize="16sp"`

Answer (score 0):

You just could make your custom tab buttons and it is quite easy and straightforward:

Create a normal like xml layout for the tab. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rlayout"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon4"
        android:src="@drawable/somedrawable"
        android:layout_height="42dp" 
        android:layout_width="42dp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="News" 
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_below ="@+id/icon4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your tab activity class infalte this layout, like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater0 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view0 = inflater0.inflate(R.layout.tabbuttonlayout, null);
```

Afterwards just use it normally in the tab host:

```
th = getTabHost();
th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("tag0").setIndicator(view0).setContent(intent0));
```

I hope this helps to better customize your tab.